# Basic PHP While Loop to display each records on a new line

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to return a basic list from a table in PHP but for some reason it returns the results in one long string instead of displaying the next record on a new line. I have done something similar a while ago but I don't use PHP that often so I'm guessing I am missing a fairly obvious mistake. Any help is appreciated.

My current code looks like this.

```
<?php

require_once("dbconnect.php"); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM clients";

$dbRecords = mysql_query($query, $dbConnect) 
or die("Problem reading table: " + mysql_error());

$clientName = $dbRecords["clientName"];

while ($arrRecords = mysql_fetch_array($dbRecords)) 
{
     $clientName .= $arrRecords["clientName"];
}

?>

<div>
<?php
     echo '<h2>Client List</h2>';
     echo $clientName; echo'<br />'; echo'<br />';
?>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding `"/r/n"` with double quotes and did you use html tags without the `<html></html>` and everything that should have been in between  ?

Answer (score 4):

Don't do

```
$clientName = $dbRecords["clientName"];
```

because `$dbRecords` is the resultset resource; just initialise `$clientName` to an empty string, then loop

```
$clientName = '';

while ($arrRecords = mysql_fetch_array($dbRecords)) {
     $clientName .= $arrRecords["clientName"] . '<br />';
}
```

adding the newline (`<br />`) in your loop

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that. Need to brush up on my PHP.

Comment: As @9997 says in their answer, as the MySQL extension is deprecated in favour of the improved MySQLi or PDO extensions, you really should be using those instead, and using prepared statements with bind variables

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something like this?

```
<?php

require_once("dbconnect.php"); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM clients";

$dbRecords = mysql_query($query, $dbConnect) 
or die("Problem reading table: " + mysql_error());

echo "<h2>Client List</h2>";

while ($arrRecords = mysql_fetch_array($dbRecords)) {
     echo $arrRecords["clientName"] . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Also, please don't use mysql_* functions any more, as they have been deprecated. Look into MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
 <?php

    require_once("dbconnect.php"); 

    $query = "SELECT * FROM clients";

    $dbRecords = mysql_query($query, $dbConnect) 
    or die("Problem reading table: " + mysql_error());



    while ($arrRecords = mysql_fetch_array($dbRecords)) 
    {
         $clientName[] = $arrRecords["clientName"];
    }

    ?>

    <div>
    <?php
         echo '<h2>Client List</h2>';
         echo implode('<br />',$clientName);
    ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this example help you convenience output

```
<?php

require_once("dbconnect.php"); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM clients";

$dbRecords = mysql_query($query, $dbConnect) 
or die("Problem reading table: " + mysql_error());

$clientName[] = $dbRecords["clientName"];

while ($arrRecords = mysql_fetch_array($dbRecords)) 
{
 $clientName[] = $arrRecords["clientName"];
}

?>

<div>
<?php
 echo '<h2>Client List</h2>';
 echo implode('<br />', $clientName); // Output line break
?>
</div>
```

By this way you can print your list with line break, bullet list etc easily. I hope this will help.

Thank you.